# parenthesis in a directory name in bash script

Tags: bash, matlab, shell, octave

I get the *error executing bash syntax error near unexpected token `('*

I know the error is caused by the **')'** but I thought placing the commands in-between **' '** is suppose to allow the parenthesis in a directory name.  How can I fix this without renaming the name?

```
bash -c 'cd /tmp/h1/clients/04212015142432811_Fs_1000_ahh/pls/03sox_a_Fs_1000_ahh_(000_bit)_(0.0000
0sig_in_deg)_to_(508_bit)_(30.00000sig_in_deg) && exec bash xfade.sh'
```

please note:
It's being called from inside octave a math program like matlab

Comment: The `bash -c` is messing that up. Why do you need it at all?

Comment: It's being called from inside octave a math program like matlab

Comment: ...which doesn't answer the question (at least, not for someone not already having knowledge of Octave). Maybe if you linked to the relevant Octave docs, _that_ might help.

Comment: ...to explain a little better why the quotes aren't helping you here: They're consumed by the outer shell (the shell that's *starting* `bash -c`, not the shell *started by* `bash -c`), so they're no longer present when the inner shell is invoked.

Comment: You say "I get the *error executing bash syntax error near unexpected token '('*... I know the error is caused by the ')'...". Why would you think that, if the shell tells you the problem is X, that it's really Y instead? The error is with the open parenthesis, not the closing one... Don't second-guess the shell, read what it's telling you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the path inside of the command string passed to the bash subshell.  E.g.:

```
bash -c 'cd '"'"'/tmp/h1/clients/04212015142432811_Fs_1000_ahh/pls/03sox_a_Fs_1000_ahh_(000_bit)_(0.00000sig_in_deg)_to_(508_bit)_(30.00000sig_in_deg) && exec bash xfade.sh'"'"''
```

You get the error because running bash -c passes the argument string to a new shell.  The argument string will have the single quotes stripped by the outer (invoking) shell.

UPDATED: to correctly quote single quotes inside single quotes as pointed out by Charles Duffy

Comment: Backslash-escaping single quotes doesn't work inside single-quoted strings. `'"'"'` is the typical way to do it, ugly as that is.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you bothering with an outer shell? Quote the argument to `cd`:

```
(cd '/tmp/h1/clients/04212015142432811_Fs_1000_ahh/pls/03sox_a_Fs_1000_ahh_(000_bit)_(0.00000sig_in_deg)_to_(508_bit)_(30.00000sig_in_deg)' && exec bash xfade.sh)
```

If you really *must* use an extra `bash -c`...

```
dirname='/tmp/h1/clients/04212015142432811_Fs_1000_ahh/pls/03sox_a_Fs_1000_ahh_(000_bit)_(0.00000sig_in_deg)_to_(508_bit)_(30.00000sig_in_deg)'
bash -c 'cd "$1" && exec bash xfade.sh' _ "$dirname"
```

Comment: That leaves you in the directory. To avoid that, surround the entire command with parentheses.

Comment: Fair 'nuff; might as well put the `exec` back, if we're doing an explicit subshell.

Comment: I guess you could put the `exec` back, but I wouldn't bother.

Comment: It's being called from inside octave a math program like matlab

Answer (score 1):

Can you use double quotes for bash -c?

```
 bash -c "cd '/tmp/h1/clients/04212015142432811_Fs_1000_ahh/pls/03sox_a_Fs_1000_ahh_(000_bit)_(0.00000sig_in_deg)_to_(508_bit)_(30.00000sig_in_deg)' && exec bash xfade.sh"
```

Comment: This is a bit risky if the filename could be controlled by an outside actor. Consider someone putting `$(foo)` into a literal.